# Springboot - @Autowired null with injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring-boot project and I need to get values from application.properties file because of profiles.

But when injecting a config file in the class, the object return null.

Application.properties:

```
server.ip=000.000.000.000
server.port=0000
```

Config Class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server")
public class AppProperties {

    private String ip;
    private Integer port;

... getters and setters
```

the class where I need the values:

```
@Component
public class Teste {

    @Autowired
    private AppProperties properties;

...
socket = new Socket(properties.getIp(), properties.getPort());
```

On debugging, at the start of the application, the values in AppProperties get a correct value.

Comment: And you got NPE where exaclty?

Comment: For me your code works. Do you have the `spring-boot-configuration-processor`
dependency included in your build file?
STS warns about this on `@ConfigurationProperties` when it is missing.

Comment: *i nedd get values from application.properties file because of profiles.* Umm i don't get why would you do this "because of profiles". Both things exists and can be used separately.

Comment: remove that `@Component` from `AppProperties` this should be sufficient `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server")`

Comment: Nullpointer in variable "properties" on start socket. I have spring-boot-configuration-processor dependency.  I need use profiles because different environments. I have 3 configuration files: application.properties, application-pro.properties and application-dev.properties. The configurations about database work correctly in all environments. The properties "ip" and "port" exists in all application.properties files.

Comment: If `@Value("${server.ip}")` didn't work, it means that your properties file is not in the spring environment. What is the _complete_ path of your properties file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I get null values for properties because I instantiate a Teste class with `new Teste().`

The Solution is use Teste class with Intection.

```
@Autowired
private Teste teste;
```

Comment: Yes. I create a new answer to facilitate the search of other users with the same problem. it's wrong? This is my first question on Stackoverflow. Excuse me.

Comment: Right now its super mess. Moreover you accepted answer that is not an answer so whats the point of *create a new answer to facilitate the search of other users with the same problem.* if it is not considered solution here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Value annotation to access the property values from application.properties file like this

```
@Value("${<propertname>}")
private String userBucketPath;
```

Comment: Nope @ConfigurationProperties are to map props into objects directly.

Comment: Yes I accept, But this can access individual properties value and it also may be useful.

Comment: Well if you rly want to go this way, lets paste link to spring documentation as whats in it "might be usefull as well". Focus on given scenario.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. No success using @Value annotation: @Value("${server.ip}")

Comment: My best bet is that OP is doing something like `new Teste()`.

Comment: I bet on that too, but what could be causing this?

Comment: *I bet on that too, but what could be causing this* You are.

Comment: Yes @Antoniossss... I did when I called the Teste class. Thanks for your attention. It's works.

Comment: How is that even considered an answer?? Problem is OP don't know what DI is nor the basics of how it works and WHEN it will NOT work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like correct but I would like to suggest you try with below steps also:

1. Use @PropertySource annotation to define properties location. (I knew default location is classpath).
2. If you really need to add a profile to your project. Create a new application property file like application-{profile-name}.properties and while starting an application pass JVM argument **-Dspring.profiles.active={profile-name}**.

I don't know it's exact need or answer for you. I'm just trying to share an additional step.

Comment: Thank's for your answer.
I Have 3 configuration files:
application.properties, application-pro.properties and application-dev.properties.
The configurations about database work correctly. 
No succes using @PropertySource annotation